# Error in dax formula

Tags: excel, sum, dax

i'm new to dax. im trying to sum the amount of fatalities per year.
My formula:

```
= SUMMARIZE (
    'TableCrash',
    'TableCrash'[Year],
    "Fatal", SUM ( 'TableCrash'[Fatalities] )
)
```

-
example:

```
SUMMARIZE(<table>, <groupBy_columnName>[, <groupBy_columnName>]…[, <name>, <expression>]…)
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492171.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with your formula. The problem is how you are using it. Because it returns a table you would usually incorporate this snippet into a larger formula. You can install [DAX Studio](https://daxstudio.codeplex.com/) into Excel to test these snippets. In this case you would execute:

```
EVALUATE
 (
    SUMMARIZE (
        'TableCrash',
        'TableCrash'[Year],
        "Fatal", SUM ( 'TableCrash'[Fatalities] )
    )
)
```

But if you have a table that contains Year and Fatalities you don't need any formula to calculate sum of Fatalities. Try to drop both fields into a Power View or pivot table and Fatalities will sum automagically.